# Modelo de Datos Inventario TipoOpearacion Movimientos

Tags: sql-server, estructuras-de-datos

Tengo una duda en mi modelo de datos en la tabla Movimientos, en dicha tabla tengo un campo AfectadoId, El cual se va a relacionar con Ventas, Compras, Promociones, Premio, Donacion, TrasladoAlmacenes, etc.
En la Tabla TipoOperacion es donde iran estas operaciones que acabo de mencionar.
[image: Modelado de datos]

¿Como puedo controlar la integridad referencial de AfectadoId que esta en Movimientos?, ¿habría otra solucion de modelado para este caso?

Podria ser otra opcion este modelado.
[image: Solucion de modelado]

En la tabla `Operaciones` registrar el `ID afectado` en el cual indico el tipo de operacion, mediante `TipoOpearacionId` y no estaria realcionado con `Compras`, `Ventas`, `Promocion`, etc. La integridad referencial se podría controlar por un Triggers.

Comment: No usaria trigger para lo que plantas, si tienes las tablas de Compras, Ventas, etc crea un campo para cada una generando la relacion, son muchos campos, si puede ser pero el el modelo correcto que asegura la integridad.

Comment: Leandro,Me recomiendas que ponga CompraId, VentaId, PromocionId, etc en Movimientos, si es una Venta se ingreasara el ID Venta y el resto seria null, ¿cuando quiera hacer una busqueda por Venta tendría que especificar en mi query `NOT NULL AND VentaId`?  algo asi.

Comment: claro podrias trabajar el null o podrias tener el campo de TipoOperacion en donde indiques que es un registro de venta, entonces sabras a cual campo acceder.

Comment: Leandro asi es, el campo TipoOperacionId me ayuda, tema cerrado. que vueltas le di a este tema, la Herencia no resultaba en este caso, :D

Comment: Voy a marcar esta pregunta basada en opiniones. No se ve con claridad cuál es el problema, el OC ya tiene una solución, _"habría otra solucion de modelado para este caso"_, pero pide opiniones. Me baso en [esta guía](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sigas ese camino porque es una pesima idea

En la tabla Movimientos define dos campos VentaId y CompraId (esto por supuesto permitiran null)

Entonces al insertar el registro en Movimiento asignas VentaId en caso de ser una venta o a CompraId en caso de ser una compra, dejando el que no corresponda en null

No se puede relacionar un unico campo con dos tablas diferentes

Comment: Hola Leandro, modifique la pregunta, revisa porfavor, que te parece esa supuesta solucion